# Is there a SEO benefit of a 'reverse canonical redirect' back to the 'friendly' URL?

Tags: redirects, iis7, seo, url-rewriting

As far as I understand, you should have a single URL to access a given page on a website to prevent duplicate issues.  With this in mind I have setup IIS7 Rewrite to point my friendly URLs to my .aspx pages. e.g. `/category/widgets/` has a **rewrite** to `/category.aspx?id=widgets`

Should I allow either of these URLs to resolve my web page, or should I also 301 **redirect** `/category.aspx?id=widgets` to `/category/widgets/` so that there is only a single URL that resolves the page?

Comment: What is a `301 rewrite`? If you're rewriting the URL, then it shouldn't be sending a 301 redirect response. The rewriting should happen internally with the client simply receiving a `200 OK` response with the contents.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for fixing that. I was just worried that you might create a redirect loop if you have two 301 redirects pointing to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should 301 redirect /category.aspx?id=widgets to /category/widgets/ so that there is only a single URL that resolves the page.

Make sure that you don't accidentally create a redirect loop.

The alternate way is to use the [rel="canonical" meta-tag](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394) in your code, but as you are using IIS7 the redirect should be simpler to implement.

Comment: As an alternative to the 301 redirect, would I be better returning a 404 response to `/category.aspx?id=widgets`?

Comment: No - your original pages may have links pointing to them. Returning a 404 will cause any reputation built up to be lost. Pass the reputation along by redirecting with a 301.